# cannot load such file -- 2.3/gherkin_lexer_en,please let me know how to fix this in windows?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash-android

cannot load such file -- 2.3/gherkin_lexer_en
Couldn't load 2.3/gherkin_lexer_en
The $LOAD_PATH was:
lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/bin/../lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/multi_json-1.12.1/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/gherkin-2.12.2
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/multi_test-0.1.2/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-support-3.5.0/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.5.0/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.6/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/byebug-9.0.6
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.20/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/slowhandcuke-0.0.3/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/escape-0.0.4/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/luffa-2.0.0/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.2/lib
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib

contents of Gemfile.lock

addressable (2.5.0, 2.4.0)
awesome_print (1.7.0)
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
builder (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
bundler (1.14.4)
byebug (9.0.6)
calabash-android (0.8.2)
calabash-cucumber (0.20.0)
capybara (2.12.1, 2.12.0, 2.10.1)
CFPropertyList (2.3.5, 2.3.3)
childprocess (0.6.1, 0.5.9)
clipboard (1.1.1)
cliver (0.3.2)
colorize (0.8.1)
command_runner_ng (0.1.0)
commonwatir (4.0.0)
cucumber (1.3.20)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.3, 1.2.5)
edn (1.1.1)
escape (0.0.4)
ffi (1.9.17 x64-mingw32, 1.9.14 x64-mingw32)
firewatir (1.9.4)
geocoder (1.4.3, 1.4.1, 1.4.0)
gherkin (4.0.0, 2.12.2)
headless (2.3.1)
httpclient (2.8.3, 2.8.2.4)
i18n (0.8.0, 0.7.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
json (default: 1.8.3)
luffa (2.0.0)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.8.5)
multi_json (1.12.1)
multi_test (0.1.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.7.0.1 x64-mingw32, 1.6.8.1 x64-mingw32)
parallel (1.10.0, 1.9.0)
parallel_calabash (0.2.4)
parallel_tests (2.13.0, 2.9.0)
poltergeist (1.13.0, 1.11.0)
power_assert (1.0.1, 0.3.1, 0.2.6)
psych (default: 2.1.0)
public_suffix (2.0.5)
rack (2.0.1)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rake (12.0.0, 11.3.0, 10.4.2)
rdoc (default: 4.2.1)
retriable (2.0.2)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
rspec-support (3.5.0)
rubygems-update (2.6.10)
rubyXL (3.3.22)
rubyzip (1.2.1, 1.2.0)
run_loop (2.3.0, 2.2.4, 2.2.2)
selendroid (0.4.0)
selenium-webdriver (3.1.0, 3.0.5, 3.0.0)
slowhandcuke (0.0.3)
test-unit (3.2.3, 3.2.1, 3.1.5)
thor (0.19.4, 0.19.1)
watir (6.1.0, 5.0.0)
watir-webdriver (0.9.3)
websocket (1.2.4, 1.2.3)
websocket-driver (0.6.5, 0.6.4)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
xpath (2.0.0)

contents of gemfile:

source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'calabash-android', '0.8.2'
gem 'calabash-cucumber', '0.20.0'
gem 'cucumber', '1.3.20'
gem 'rspec-expectations'
gem 'poltergeist'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'firewatir'
gem 'watir'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'headless'
gem 'rake'
gem 'parallel_tests'
gem 'slowhandcuke'
gem 'selendroid'
gem 'run_loop'
gem 'test-unit'
gem 'rubyXL'
gem 'parallel_calabash'

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow , read this first before post a question again.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Gherkin (part of the Cucumber gem) does not support ruby 2.3 on Windows. Try downgrading to ruby 2.2 (you may have to downgrade to 2.0 if 2.2 doesn't work) or using a virtual machine to develop on Linux.

Comment: for Ruby 2.2  i tried doing that results "all-but-one-formatter-must-use-out-only-one-can-print-to-each-stream" error

Comment: @jash that's not a lot of info to go by, but odds are good with your massive list of gems that there's a separate conflicting gem for each version of ruby. are you cloning a project from somewhere? can you check to see if a .ruby-version file exists?

Comment: ,First of all,I appreciate for quick reply.we did cloned our project from git and the gems are working fine in Mac-OS.I can't see the file .ruby-version file could you please specify the path.what i can see in our project is working_version file.Thanks

Comment: @jash can you update your question to include the contents of your Gemfile and your Gemfile.lock?